# Using the ADO.NET Entity Framework to access one object from another

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net

I have the following code:

```
using (var db = new IntDB())
{
    var subscription =
        (from s in db.Subscription
         where s.SubsciptionId == subscriptionId
         select s).FirstOrDefault();
    if (subscription != null)
    {
        db.DeleteObject(subscription);
        db.SaveChanges();

        EntityKeyMember articleId = (EntityKeyMember)subscription.ArticleReference
                                 .EntityKey.EntityKeyValues.GetValue(0);
        var article = (from a in db.Article
                       where a.ArticleId == (int)articleId.Value
                       select a).FirstOrDefault();
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(article.WebUrl) && article.WebUrl.Equals(@"/ExploderLists"))
        {
            var lstAppIntrfc = new ListAppInterface();
            // the articleId is stored in the entity key here, the article object hasn't been instanicated
            // so it's easier to just get it from the EntityKey.                            
            lstAppIntrfc.RemoveEmailFromListByArticleID((int)articleId.Value, subscription.EmailAddress);
        }
    }
}
```

and here's my question. After I load the `Subscription` object with the LINQ code, I find that the `Article` property of the subscription instance is NULL! I can find the `entityKey` for the article in the subscription instance, but I have to then run LINQ to load the article instance that I need for the final IF statement there.

Have I just gone totally off the reservation here and I am not understanding how to use the entity objects or is this the only way to do this?

Comment: Is it just me, or do you try to get an Article out of a Subscription right after deleting it?

Comment: Yeah actually I am. I am in this method ready to delete records/column value from 2 desperate tables. The common key is the ArticleID, that's why I want to get ahold of it. One of the tables in the Entity framework, the other I am just using straight ADO.net. It's add on thing to consultant work, you know how that goes, it's always ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Include` method to eager load the `Article` with the `Subscription`.

```
using (var db = new IntDB())
{
    var subscription = db.Subscription.Include("Article")
          .Where(s => s.SubsciptionId == subscriptionId).FirstOrDefault();
    if (subscription != null)
    {
        var article = subscription.Article;
        db.DeleteObject(subscription);
        db.SaveChanges();

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(article.WebUrl) && article.WebUrl.Equals(@"/ExploderLists"))
        {
            var lstAppIntrfc = new ListAppInterface();
            // the articleId is stored in the entity key here, the article object hasn't been instanicated
            // so it's easier to just get it from the EntityKey.                            
            lstAppIntrfc.RemoveEmailFromListByArticleID((int)articleId.Value, subscription.EmailAddress);
        }
    }
}
```